# Display items depending on whether a file exists in a specific folder, and to create/delete the file depending on what the button is set to

Tags: javascript

Assets: (dead link, may repost when I have the time to make it all over again)

The file that needs to be created when the button is clicked while being displayed as a red face is `testing.dat` in the folder `%AppData%/CVN All Access/watchlist`, the folder should be created if it doesn't exist. Likewise, the `testing.dat` should be deleted if the face is green and is clicked (the folder `%AppData%/CVN All Access/watchlist` should remain though).

Pretty much every solution I could find is too complex and/or doesn't work. My problem recommends a simple and easy-to-understand solution.

If the folder name `%AppData%` cannot be used in JavaScript, maybe use `C:/CVN All Access/watchlist` as the destination instead.

Comment: You have to work with the AJAX request and using the PHP file_exists function you will get this done, using Pure JS is difficult but when you use PHP with JS it would be very easy.

Comment: Interesting. I never really worked with PHP so I didn't really think of that.

The reason I wanted to use "%AppData%" instead of "C:/Users/me/AppData" is because I want it to look in the "AppData" folder regardless of the user name, otherwise it will only work if the user name is "me".

Do you happen to know the exact command to get it to work?